# Google sheets, make checking one checkbox uncheck another

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to make it so that if, in a row, column A is checked checking column B will uncheck it, and vice versa. For what I'm trying to do "Neither" is acceptable, "Or" is acceptable, but "And" is unacceptable. I need both boxes to be clickable. Putting in a formula, so far, has resulted in the box becoming unclickable and ONLY controllable via whatever is affecting it in the formula, i.e. another checkbox. Is this possible?

I made a test sheet to show what I’m looking for:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hChnL86Jz_tFOMtmG3PiCzM1zeTVhQqJ7uHW3w7vdMk

(Also, I couldn’t find a checkbox tag and I’m not allowed to create one if anybody could do that for me.)

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].